# Rotate UIViewControllers in UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, autorotate

I have `UIViewController` with `UIScrollView` in it.
`UIScrollView` contains multiple `UIViewControllers` (something like [PageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html) Apple example).
 
Each inner `UIViewController` in `UIScrollView` is able to handle the change of `UIInterfaceOrientation` and to redraw it's view.
But when the `UIViewControllers` are in `UIScrollView` the rotations events never reaches inner `UIViewControllers`.

How can I make those inner UIViewControllers to handle rotation events?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Only a viewController in a viewController structure (like tabbarcontroller or navigationcontroller) gets (and handles) rotation events. If you just added the views of some viewControllers, they won't actually rotate, but they will change their framesize accordingly to the new size of the main view. In general you should use autoresizingMasks on every view. Read about them in the documentation.

But in a scrollView there is probably no autolayouting possible. You could overwrite layoutSubviews: in your main view to handle the layout of all scrollView subviews based on the scrollView frame.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can detect when the device is rotated, then using the `transform` property apply the necessary rotation programmatically using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2)`, for example...